# How can I view "archived" Google Chrome history — i.e. history older than three months?

Tags: google-chrome

I need to recover old history. Google Chrome only stores the last 3 months in the "History" file.

The rest is in the "Archived History" file. How can I view this older history?

Comment: Here you go [How open Archived History file](http://unlockforus.blogspot.it/2008/09/how-opening-google-chrome-files-history.html)

Comment: what is this? shareware? from 2008?

Comment: Isn't SQLite free?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can Chrome browser history be exported to an HTML file?](https://superuser.com/questions/602252/can-chrome-browser-history-be-exported-to-an-html-file)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `History` and `Archived History` files are in fact an SQLite databases.

You can open them using [SQLite Database Browser](http://sqlitebrowser.sourceforge.net/) or one of the [many other programs that can open SQLite databases](http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=ManagementTools).

Comment: are you 100% sure? it says 'archived history' is not a sqlite file. have you tried it yourself?

Comment: yes, I opened both with SQLite Database browser. You may also try SQLite Manager, which is a Firefox plugin: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/

Comment: ok it's doing the same thing, 'probably not a sqlite..' -- should chrome be closed? on the firefox addon, it doesn't even show the file, should the file be named .sqlite ?

Comment: yep needed .sqlite at the end, then i realized what i needed wasn't yet archived and was still in history....

Comment: @designparadise You don't have to rename the file to .sqlite (in the Firefox extension select "All Files" in the list next to the File Name field)

Comment: @designparadise yes, I think it's best to close chrome before opening the database.

Comment: @w0lf, **Seems like there is no more `Archived History` file anymore.**

Comment: Where does the "Archived History" database reside?

Answer (score 7):

## I think this is no longer possible

Edit: I think you can't view archived history anymore. See the comments to the other answers.

#### My old answer

<del>Download [ChromeHistoryView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/chrome_history_view.html) (freeware). Click "Options > Advanced Options". Point the tool to the location of your Archived History file.</del>

<del>The tool is made for Windows.</del>

<del>If you don't have access to a Windows PC, that's okay. I've found that it works fine in [Wine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wine_%28software%29), so you can also use it on Mac and Linux.</del>

Answer (score 6):

History older than 90 days is stored in the `Archived History` sqlite database file. As with the Chrome install, the actual location of the actual sqlite file varies by operating system. Once it is located you may have to close Google Chrome to unlock the file then open it with your favorite sqlite data browser.

**Windows XP**

```
C:\Documents and Settings\%USERNAME%\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Archived History
```

**Windows 7 or Vista**

```
C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Archived History
```

**Mac OS X**

```
~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Archived History
```

**Linux**

```
~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Archived History
```

As of the writing of this comment the Archived History database has the following tables:

```
meta
urls
visits
visit_source
keyword_search_terms
```

To query the file by visit and URL

```
--- Code below finds visits between 01/01/2013 and 02/01/2013 
--- on a windows machine which explains the timestamp conversion   
SELECT 
visits.visit_time
, datetime(visits.visit_time/1000000-11644473600,'unixepoch','localtime')
, urls.url, urls.title
FROM visits
LEFT JOIN urls ON visits.url = urls.id 
WHERE visits.visit_time > (strftime('%s','2013-01-01') + 11644473600) * 1000000
AND visits.visit_time < (strftime('%s','2013-02-01') + 11644473600) * 1000000
LIMIT 100
```

Comment: The visit datatime format is based on the information from this SO question and specifically the information submitted by @Squiggly http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2141537/convert-datetime-fields-in-chrome-history-file-sqlite-to-readable-format

Comment: Unfortunately, Google decided to remove the Archived History from our computers sometime in the Fall of 2014. Now we're only able to see about 90 days of History (no more archived history).

Comment: I just reported this issue to Google, here https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=465754

Comment: @ElectricAutomation, Seriously that's the worst thing that have ever happened to Chrome. Silent deletion of all browsing data.

Comment: Sad, but no surprise, because it is Google.. However probably somebody finds useful what I found. I do have also the History-20220618210410.820131.backup file which resides in the same directory as History file. The .backup file contains at least additional 3 months of browsing history. I don't remember that I explicitly generated this file. My Chrome version is 104.0.5112.81.

Answer (score 5):

Use [history.google.com](https://history.google.com) - it also stores all the browsing history.

Comment: Yes more than 90 days here!

Answer (score 3):

There is no `Archived History` in new Chrome versions. I developed a Chrome extension [U History (available on chrome web store)](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/u-history/nkokmdpokpgocgabofnpkandjgchljgf) to save your history to you Google Drive in months. It will automatically save once you authorized (If you want to make sure the history are saved you can do manually). Moreover you can read your saved history. If you run into any problems or find any bugs pls feel free to contact me.

Comment: Please do not post the same answer to multiple questions. If the same information really answers both questions, then one question (usually the newer one) should be closed as a duplicate of the other. You can indicate this by [voting to close it as a duplicate](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/close-questions) or, if you don't have enough reputation for that, [raise a flag](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) to indicate that it's a duplicate. Otherwise tailor your answer to this question and don't just paste the same answer in multiple places.

Answer (score 0):

I had no "default" folder. For me history was saved @ `C:\Users\user\AppData\local\Google\Chrome\profile1` in a file called `history` with no extension.

It is an sqlite database file. You can open it with DB Browser for SQLite. Google Chrome must be closed to open it.