# How to record the browsing history in Chrome indefinitely?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, history

I first thought it was a bug that my browsing history in Chrome was getting lost but there seems to be a [hard limit of 90 days](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95589) for it: “Your History page shows the websites you've visited on Chrome in the last 90 days. It doesn’t store pages from secure websites, pages you've visited in Incognito mode, or pages you've already deleted from your browsing history.” The part about the Incognito mode and deleted entries is intuitive, but I’m dismayed to find that all the rest of my older browsing history is lost.

Is there a trick, app, or extension that works around that and records all browsing history, HTTP and HTTPS, indefinitely? Thank you!

Comment: Run a script to record the log file where the history is stored every 45 days or so and keep that as reference. Can it then be accessible from Chrome ?

Comment: Can you please give an example on how having old history can come in useful? I am genuinely interested.

Comment: MegaBluejay, it’s a very frequent use case for me – every other day or so – that I’m like, “Oh, I read this blog post once that I can link to you [use as reference here, get those numbers from, etc.]. I think the title was something with ‘fish’ in it. I’ll check my browser history.” It’s usually a nightmare to Google such things a year or two later because of how little I remember about the wording, title, address, etc., and how unknown many of these sources are but my history only has a dozen or so hits for “fish.” (Or really zero at the moment.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this directly in chrome history, but there are multiple third-party solutions that allow you to back up existing history regularly. One that is automated and seems to be all round the best is [this extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/history-trends-unlimited/pnmchffiealhkdloeffcdnbgdnedheme). You an also use [this one](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/export-history/hcohnnbbiggngobheobhdipbgmcbelhh?hl=en-US) to manually export into a spreadsheet.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like this was answered here: [How can I view "archived" Google Chrome history — i.e. history older than three months?](https://superuser.com/questions/414346/how-can-i-view-archived-google-chrome-history-i-e-history-older-than-three)

TL;DR use an extension or SQLite to access the archived history db